# Webview randomly does not readjust after orientation change on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

When change orientation of iOS device the contents of Webview don't always adjust to new orientation. It cuts off to what seems to be width of the space that it occupied in previous orientation. Screenshot below

[image]

On orientation change I call orientationchange event

```
evalJavascript("var e= document.createEvent('Events');" +
    "e.initEvent('orientationchange',true, false); document.dispatchEvent(e)");
```

In HTML I have viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

What's interesting is that this does not happen to other pages like New York Times home page, which I load locally. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Put this HTML code into your website header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device- width, height=device-height">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

This should ensure that your website is app/mobile accessible.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, same thing. Really weird.